# Protected Video not working on ios10

Tags: html5-video, ios10

I have been working with HTML video files as per the [W3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) code. I have found that if I host the videos locally they work fine locally and on server space that is not password protected. However putting the same files under htaccess protection (or a third party user protection system), and logging in with a password to view video HTML causes the videos to fail on ios10. As a short term fix I have hosted the videos on server space that is not password protected, and kept the actual HTML video page protected, which works, but is not good for sensitive material.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be occurring because the MIME types aren't set. On a Linux server you may add an .htaccess file to the server with the following in it:

```
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm
```

It is worth noting that this appears to be a problem specific to ios10, that has been identified and fixed in the ios10.2 beta. I tested this and couldn't replicate the problem on the ios10.2 beta.